# Kendo UI Treeview page jump in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, kendo-ui, internet-explorer-11, kendo-treeview

If the treeview extends below the browsers visible height and causes a vertical scroll-bar, on clicking nodes within the treeview causes a page jump in Internet Explorer 11.

This bug is noticeable on the Kendo-ui demos [Tree View Demo](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/treeview/index.html).

Is there a quick fix for IE11? As this bug does not appear when using Chrome or Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this is caused by the widget calling `jQuery.focus()` on the `<ul>` or one of its descendants.

To fix this, you'd need to make sure the treeview container is confined to the viewport. So when you create the treeview and when you resize the window, you need to test whether `.k-treeview` is partially outside of the viewport (e.g. by using `jQuery.offset()` and the element's height, then comparing it to the window height), and adjust the container height accordingly.

The alternative would be to change the widget code to not use `.focus()` on IE (but I'm not sure what the side-effects would be).

Comment: That's great, I've also fixed the height of the Kendo treeview to minimize this issue. It would be great if Internet Explorer acted like other browsers. Not sure I like the idea of re-sizing it based on view-port. Will look into it further, Cheers!